# react native for ios seems to include a library from a previous project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-library

So I am trying my first few tutorials with react native and therefore am still quite unfamiliar. I had followed this tutorial for using an npm camera in an IOS app. The camera worked find but I had to go an link this library for the camera. I tried it both the manual approach and rnpm. However, now I have a different tutorial on the go which I was messing around with prior to the camera one, and the simulator throws this error.

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect'), and further down there is also an error about a file which I know was only in my other tutorial(because I wrote it).

So this seems to me like xCode or the node modules for react are somehow still holding this code. I had previously added an entry to the header search paths under the projects build settings, but I looked at it and this path I needed for the camera is not there. So I don't know where this is coming in from.

I ran react-native run-ios on my project, and I tried cleaning the product in xcode and running from there. So far I haven't had very much luck figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was a simple human error on my behalf. I will post an answer to it anyhow as it might help some react-native beginners. So I had recently made the switch from linux to OSX, and when I started on there linux I had always run the packager for react native manually, and then I found out on OSX I can just run react-native run-ios in the root of the project and it starts another terminal window with the packager running.

The react-native packager was causing the issue. When I ran the react-native run-ios command the following day(didn't turn off my computer) the packager in the other window was forgotten about and I thought it be smart enough to kill that process and restart a new packager for the other project, but it didn't. Hopefully if anyone makes the same assumption you can save some time with this answer.